# Python .exe file not running in cmd prompt

Tags: python

I have some python script which is having more number of `.py` files, So I have generated `.exe` file for that, and I am trying to run using command prompt. I am unable to run `.exe` file in cmd prompt but when I tried to run on my friends laptop it is working fine.

I tried in cmd like below:

```
C:\pythonworkspace\Verification.exe -i C:\pythonworkspace\kpi_verification_2.0\config\Verification_config.xml
```

getting error as below:

```
Cannot open self C:\pythonworkspace\Verification.exe or archive 
C:\pythonworkspace\Verification.pkg
```

Please help me where it is going wrong.

Comment: I assume you are using windows .. what OS does your friend's laptop running on..

Comment: yes me & my friend both using windows 10

Comment: try to put `Verification.exe` in your python directory and run it there. For example `C:\python27\Verification.exe`

Comment: Hi Ssein, I tried your suggestion but throwing same issue again.